# Does regenerate or any other spell halt the dying process of a flail snail who has lost all it's tentacles?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

**Scenario**

The party happens across a **Flail snail** being mobbed by some bugbears (Random encounter). They killed the bugbears and the **Flail snail started** **wailing** **(All of its tentacles were severed and dead)**. Can the druid cast ***regenerate*** on it to **reattach the tentacles** (Snail did not reflect the spell).

What other spells or methods could be used to save the flail snail, especially for lower level parties?

Comment: I've reopened this by combining your original with the larger request you had in the update. I'm sorry about the frustration yesterday, and I clearly wasn't as helpful by taking the harder line of not changing questions after answers have been submitted and voted on.

Comment: @NautArch Thank you so much. I apologize for not being as compromising then as I normally am.

Comment: Bad days for both of us - they happen! Let me know if there's anything I should clarify in my answer. I was fairly surprised about the result myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, *regenerate* will halt the dying process

Per the [Flail Snail](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flail-snail) stat block(Volo's, 144)

> Healing magic that restores limbs, such as the *regenerate* spell, can halt this dying process.

The spell you ask about is specifically listed as an option to halt the dying process.

## Unless the Flail Snail dies, there are no other options (besides *wish*)

Unfortunately, the only other healing spells that will regrow missing parts also require the target to first be dead:

- *[resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resurrection)* (PHB, 272)
- *[clone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone)* (PHB, 222)
- *[reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate)* (PHB, 271)

*[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* (PHB, 288) remains a possibility, but that isn't a low-level option.

**[Ring of Regeneration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-regeneration)** (DMG, 191) is also an option, although the flail snail will need to attune to it in order to get the effects.

### Low Level options

The only option there is for low-level creatures is going to be in hiring spellcasting services that can cast *regenerate*.

Comment: When exactly is the dying halted? Does it happen when the spell is cast, or only once the tentacles regenerate?

Comment: @RyanCThompson Presumably it's as soon as the spell is cast, since it says the dying process is halted by "healing magic such as the Regenerate spell", not "getting its tentacles back".